# Setting up UISlider

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I've setup a UISlider to accept values from 0 to 10. I want to be able to have the slider execute static commands for each increment of the UISlider value, from 0 to 10. I've linked the UISlider with a button called `zoomControl`. For example, I want to do something like this:

```
- (IBAction)zoomControl
{
    if(zoom.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        // execute commands
    }

    else if(zoom.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
        // execute commands
    }

    else if(zoom.selectedSegmentIndex == 2)
    {
        // execute commands
    }

// + all the remaining statements up to 10
}
```

This was the declaration of the UISlider, made in the .h file, as well as the button:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

{
    IBOutlet UISlider *zoom;
}

- (IBAction)zoomControl;
```

The errors that I'm experiencing now have to do with the `selectedSegmentIndex` block. What is the correct syntax for the UISlider?

(The `selectedSegmentIndex` block was the syntax for the UISegmentedControl switch)

Comment: Well... what are your errors?  How have you set up the slider?  Is it on interface builder?  Or are you creating it programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a property of **UISegmentedControl** named **selectedSegmentIndex**, where you need to access the **value** property of **UISlider**.

use instead **zoom.value**

try

```
if ((int)(zoom.value + 0.5) == 0) { //do something...}
```

I've added 0.5 to round the value when type casting it to an **int** because **zoom.value** is of type **float**.